# Learning Linked Lists C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to figure out linked lists and I'm trying to make a linked list that has 2 items in each node, but I can't get it to print right, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int num;
    char word[30];
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct node *learn = NULL;
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *temp1, *p;
    int q, i = 0;
    char word1[30];

    while (i != 7)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &q);
        temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->num = q;
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp1 = p = learn;
        while (temp1 != NULL)
        {
            p = temp1;
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        if (p != NULL)
            p->next = temp;
        else
            learn = temp;
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i != 7)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            int c;
            do
            {
                c = getchar();
            } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
        }
        printf("\nEnter a word: ");
        fgets(word1, 30, stdin);
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(temp->word, word1);
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp1 = p = learn;
        while (temp1 != NULL)
        {
            p = temp1;
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        }
        if (p != NULL)
            p->next = temp;
        else
            learn = temp;
        i++;

    }

    while (learn != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", learn->num);
        learn = learn->next;
    }
    while (learn != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", learn->word);
        learn = learn->next;
    }
}
```

Here is what I input:

```
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: 7
```

Enter a word: a

Enter a word: b

Enter a word: c

Enter a word: d

Enter a word: e

Enter a word: f

Enter a word: g

And here is what I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 2):

The first while loop at the bottom is going through the entire list. "learn" is NULL at the end of the first while loop so the second loop never prints anything.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate twice memory for list's elements. Instead, you should allocate only once, and in second loop you should just add strings using `strcpy` or simillar, or you could read both number and string in the same loop.